# Session Timeout in WebSphere Cluster

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, cookies, websphere, cluster-computing

I've got a Java EE application running on a WebSphere cluster. The session-timeout is 30 minutes, and LTPA-timeout 120 minutes. User who get their session invalidated should be shown a notice on their next action after the timeout. The timeout is handled by a JSF exception handler, and on a single server this works fine. However, on a cluster, this only works if the first request after the session timeout is send to the same cluster member again (there is no session-replication). As far as I understand it, the session-cookie gets deleted after the session-timeout, but that cookie also contains the  session-affinity token, so the load balancer is free to choose any server in the cluster. But only the original member knows about the former session and produces the session-timeout exception.

Is there a way to have that warning generated on all cluster members (without enabling session-replication)?

Best regards, Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you have a cluster of JVMs and you do not have session replication there is no way for the other JVMs to know the state of that session. Session replication is used specifically to store the state of the session. There is no other mechanism for the other cluster members to know the state of the session from the original JVM the user was at.